# Angular2- Implementing css file into component

Tags: css, angular, components

I have the following in my component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'Leaders',
template: require('./Leaders.component.html'),
styleUrls: ['./bootstrap.component.css']
})
```

The component was loading fine before I added this style sheet to it.  When I attmept to run my web application it says that it, "Can't read the URL" of where my css file is.  This css file is in the same folder as my Leader html page is yet it cant find the file.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using an older version of Angular2. For the newer versions the syntax that is used is:

```
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
```

notice there is no `require()` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I have taken out require and switched to templateURL and now it says it cannot read that URL

Comment: what version of angular are you using ?

Comment: I am using version 2.1

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot comment I will write this as an answer.*

is there a specific reason for using `require(...)` in `template`.

if not, try this and make sure your `css` file name is spelled correctly:

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'Leaders',
    templateUrl: './Leaders.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bootstrap.component.css']
 })
```

hope this helps!

Comment: can you try using paths relative to the root? `'app/.../Leaders.component.html'`

Comment: It isn't throwing an error but it isn't implementing all the styles

Comment: in the tsconfig, what's in `"module":?` ?

Comment: I just changed it to module: commonjs

Comment: then you need to use moduleId in your component if you want to use paths relative to your component . add `moduleId: module.id` to your component decorator, and then use `'./Leaders.component.html'` and `'./bootstrap.component.css'`

Comment: Do I need to import anything? It is throwing me this error: "uri.match is not a function
at _split"

Comment: apparently that's a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1910). try moving to a newer version of angular2, i would suggest using angular-cli.